# How can I use pointers to get rid of the four loops that copy the matrix values?

Tags: c

I am wondering how I would use pointers to remove the need for the for loops that copy the array element by element before executing the outer for loop again. The aim of this program is to manually conduct array multiplication without using in built functions. The for loops I am trying to remove are the two nested loops copying the values for temp to temp1.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //defining variables
    int M, N, i, j, k, l, sum = 0;
    int R[5][5] = { 0 };
    int temp[5][5] = { 0 };
    int temp1[5][5] = { 0 };

    //Asking the user for the size of the array
    printf("Please enter the value of M that will be used to create an array of size M x M\nNote M must take a value between 1 and 5 inclusive\n");
    scanf_s(" %d", &M);
    while (M < 1 || M >5) {     //Checking that the array has a size between 1 and 5
        printf("Please re enter size of the array M as a value between 1 and 5:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &M);
    }

    //Asking the user for the values in the array
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if (j == 0 && i == 0) {
                printf("\nPlease enter the first element in the array:\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &R[i][j]);
                temp[i][j] = R[i][j];
            }
            else {
                printf("Please enter the next element in the array:\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &R[i][j]);
                temp[i][j] = R[i][j];
            }
    }

    //Asking the user for the power that the array multiplication will ocuur
    printf("\nTo what power would you like to calculate R to?\nNote this must be a positive interger\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    while (N <= 0) {
        printf("Please re-enter the power you would like to calculate to as a positive interger:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &N);
    }

    //Calculating the power of the array
    for (l = 0; l+1 < N; l++) {
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                    sum = sum + temp[i][k] * R[k][j];
                }
                temp1[i][j] = sum;
                sum = 0;
                temp[i][j] = &temp1[i][j]
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                temp[i][j] = temp1[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //Printing the output array
    printf("\nProduct of the matrices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%d\t", temp[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Pointers can't eliminate the need for loops.  They can only change the way you access your array elements.

Comment: `memcpy` should do. But it's unclear to me what you are doing with `temp`. This line `temp[i][j] = &temp1[i][j]` is very strange. You are saving an address into an int-array. Strange... I'm sure your compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the loop of copying `temp1` to `temp`, you can use `memcpy()`.

An array is stored continuously on memory, like this

```
+---------+---------+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| R[0][0] | R[0][1] | ... | R[1][0] | ... | R[4][4] |
+---------+---------+-----+---------+-----+---------+
```

So you can just simply copy the memory area

```c
memcpy(temp, temp1, sizeof(temp1));
```

Comment: The `memcpy` part is fine but the comment about `R` is not entirely correct as `R` is used here: `sum = sum + temp[i][k] * R[k][j];`